# Can you cite an article to your bibliography? If yes, what is the format?

Tags: citations, essay

I have written a 60 page essay. However most of my references are articles. How can I include this in the bibliography?

Comment: Is there a particular style guide you're following? AP, APA, Chicago, or the like?

Answer (score 1):

The particular style that determines the proper formatting will depend on where this article is being submitted or published. If it's for school work, then ask your instructor or check with your program guide. If it's for publication, check what your intended publication requires. Once you know that, we can provide specific help and resources.

Comment: Agreed. (This answer can be edited with specific information about references once we have this information.)